# Structure of Non-profits and Moral Hazard

Tags: microeconomics, labor-cost

When one looks at a Non-Profit Organization there are three main things people notice.

**1.**They are an Income tax exempt organization

**2.** They are primarily financed by donations

**3.**They are heavily reliant on volunteer labour

what systems are in place to see that surplus income is not redistributed among stakeholders or among board members?

Comment: Nonprofits have to file extensive tax forms (called 990s) that detail their finances and they can be audited.

Answer (score 1):

Although they are non-profit organizations, they still submit legal documents such as statement of cash flow, statement of financial position, etc.

These contain detailed information of the spending of such organizations.